# Unexpected Behavior with Parallel.For() - file not found

Tags: parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, console-application, parallel.for

I am trying to use Parallel.For() to load n # of flat files into a database. Each iteration needs to create 2 config files in a folder and then run another process that uses the config files to know how to load the flat file into Oracle. Before I decided to use a parallel option, I tested the performance benefits by iterating 1000 times, each time creating the config files. I had better than a 2x increase in speed.

I then added the part where I call the other process, and I am getting periodic errors that some of the config files I am trying to create per iteration aren't there.

Here is my stripped-down code:

```
public static void FindFilesToLoad(int monitorId)
{
    //left out code here that calls a stored procedure to get a list of ids
    fileCount = idList.Count;
    if (fileCount  != 0)
        {
           Parallel.For(0, fileCount, 

                        i =>
                        {
                            fileId = Convert.ToInt32(idList[i]);
                            //do the work here...
                            LoadFileIntoDatabase(monitorId, fileId);
                        });
        }
}

public static void LoadFileIntoDatabase(int monitorId, int fileId)
{
     stamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
     controlFile = CreateSqlLoaderControlFile(monitorId,stamp);
     controlFileName = Path.GetFileName(controlFile);
     parFile = CreateParFile(monitorId, controlFileName, stamp);

     myCommand = @"CMD.EXE";
     ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(myCommand)
         {
            WorkingDirectory = @"c:\temp\",
            Arguments = @"/c SQLLDR CONTROL=" + controlFile + " PARFILE=" + parFile ,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            UseShellExecute = false
         };

     Process process = new Process();
     process.StartInfo = startInfo;
     process.Start();
     process.WaitForExit();
     exitCode = process.ExitCode;
}
```

Error example:
SQL*Loader-500: Unable to open file (6f46ccfd-986e-427e-ab63-b7ce2396488e.ctl)
SQL*Loader-553: file not found
SQL*Loader-509: System error: The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: which line exactly exactly throws? `CreateSqlLoaderControlFile(monitorId,stamp)` ?

Comment: Thanks for replying. It was something unrelated to Parallell.For(). Just a dumb mistake I made after a long day. 

Everything appears to be working well. I have better than 3x speed increase on my dev machine (4 cores).

Comment: good for you :) It's weird though that SQL Loader does not have some .NET sdk and you have to use cmd.exe ...